# Why is there a difference in ether sent and difference in balance before and after transaction?

Tags: contract-development, truffle, gas, truffle-test

I'm doing a simple Dapp where I register a star as an NFT, using openzeppelin ERC721 contract, and then I can put it up for sale and buy it. In truffle I'm writing a test where I create a star, put it for sale then buy it. I get the balance of the buyer before and after the purchase, compute the difference and assert if it is the same as the price of the star. I took into account the gas used but there is still a tiny difference I can't understand. Here is my code:

---

Contract function

```
function buyStar(uint256 _tokenId) public  payable {
    require(starsForSale[_tokenId] > 0, "The Star should be up for sale");
    uint256 starCost = starsForSale[_tokenId];
    address ownerAddress = ownerOf(_tokenId);
    require(msg.value > starCost, "You need to have enough Ether");
    transferFrom(ownerAddress, msg.sender, _tokenId); // We can't use _addTokenTo or_removeTokenFrom functions, now we have to use _transferFrom
    address payable ownerAddressPayable = payable(ownerAddress); // We need to make this conversion to be able to use transfer() function to transfer ethers
    ownerAddressPayable.transfer(starCost);
    
    if(msg.value > starCost) {
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value - starCost);
    }
```

---

Truffle test

```
it('lets user2 buy a star and decreases its balance in ether', async() => {
    let instance = await StarNotary.deployed();
    let user1 = accounts[1];
    let user2 = accounts[2];
    let starId = 5;
    let starPrice = web3.utils.toWei(".01", "ether");
    let balance = web3.utils.toWei(".05", "ether");
    await instance.createStar('awesome star 4', starId, {from: user1});
    await instance.putStarUpForSale(starId, starPrice, {from: user1});
    let balanceOfUser1BeforeTransaction = await web3.eth.getBalance(user2);
    const balanceOfUser2BeforeTransaction = await web3.eth.getBalance(user2);
    
    const receipt = await instance.buyStar(starId, {from: user2, value: balance});

   
    const tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(receipt.tx);
    const gasCost = tx.gasPrice * receipt.receipt.gasUsed;
    console.log(`GasCost + Star Price: ${Number(gasCost) + Number(starPrice)}`);

    const balanceAfterUser2BuysStar = await web3.eth.getBalance(user2);
   
    let value = Number(balanceOfUser2BeforeTransaction) - Number(balanceAfterUser2BuysStar);
    console.log(`Difference: ${ value - (Number(gasCost) + Number(starPrice))}`);
    
    assert.equal(value, starPrice);
  });
```

---

Test output:

[image: test output]

Comment: Maybe not the answer but you can’t just cast to Number . You need to use BigNumbers library when u calculate something

Answer (score 1):

I used the BigNumbers library as suggested by @Majd, to perform the calculations and it worked as expected.

```
    const gasPrice = new web3.utils.BN(tx.gasPrice);
    const gasUsage = new web3.utils.BN(receipt.receipt.gasUsed);
    const price = new web3.utils.BN(starPrice);

    const gasCost = gasPrice.mul(gasUsage);

    const balanceAfterUser2BuysStar = await web3.eth.getBalance(user2);
   
    let value = new web3.utils.BN(balanceOfUser2BeforeTransaction).sub(new web3.utils.BN(balanceAfterUser2BuysStar));
    const x = new web3.utils.BN(value).sub(gasCost)
```